# Sense of the "Vessel has to say 'yes'" system?

Tags: supernatural

In the television series, Supernatural Season 5, throughout the series we see that Michael and a few angels torture Sam and Dean to say "yes" to give their bodies up.

My question is, What is the whole point of having the system where a person has to say yes with his free will when an angel can torture them. Isn't it a loophole in the whole system of the heaven?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thinkt he intention was to highlight the purity of the angels.  They won't/can't take a body without it willfully giving up it's body.  Even Lucifer has to have his vessel say yes.

In Castiel's case we are shown that he had his vessel go through several "trust buidling" exercises to get him to say yes.  Lucifer, however, preyed on the vessel's weaknesses to get him to say yes.

So yes, it's a loophole in the sense that the angels can torture their vessels into saying yes, but most angels are pure enough that they wouldn't do that.

Comment: I do not believe this to be the case at all. Lucifer would take a vessel if he could, there is some mechanism (presumably magical) that prevents it. Whatever that mechanism is, it's naive. Coerced consent is sufficient. This may hint even at how "free will" works in the Supernatural universe (or for that matter, the writers' own personal opinions on how it works in the real world).

Answer (score 2):

I think of the "possession" either demonic or angelic as a very intimate thing.  To have them inside your body and mind with access to your memories and thoughts.

As such a demonic possession is almost a form of rape, whereas the angels have a much more loving relationships with their hosts.

That's not to say that an angel can't attempt to manipulate the vessel in order to gain their consent (Lucifer and Sam/Michael and Dean).